How to draw filled letters (e.g. O) without write() in turtle
I created a code and easily got letters, but now I just understood that I don't know how to make them fill. I made only an E and an L and by this site user help G, but I don't understand how to make O and fill it.
This is what i made but its not the variant that is right, it should be made just by yellow colour.
import turtle as t
def O():
    t.speed(1)
    t.penup()
    t.setpos(-690, 0)
    t.pendown()
    t.pensize(40)
    t.color("yellow")
    t.circle(100)
    
    #vacuum
    t.penup()
    t.setpos(-690, 10)  
    t.pendown()
    t.color("white", "white")  
    t.begin_fill()
    t.circle(90)


How does this differ from your earlier question https://stackoverflow.com/q/78269186/51685 ?

Yep @AKX, maybe the OP wanted faster answers?

Seems to work fine for me. It draws a hollow yellow O. I don't think you need a vacuum--that happens naturally with a thick line.

I believe @ggorlen is spot-on (+1) in his advice.  Your filled circle (aka "vacuum") is covering up stuff you needn't have drawn in the first place.  Simply use a pen width that matches your desired result:
import turtle

def O():
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.setpos(-690, 0)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.pensize(10)
    turtle.color('yellow')
    turtle.circle(100)

turtle.setup(1.0, 1.0)
turtle.speed('fastest')

O()

turtle.done()

